# Order of operations for stat_smooth and scale transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some log-scaled data with an overlain linear fit line, like so:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10^(1:10 + rnorm(10)))
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

It *looks* like the linear regression line is being calculated on the transformed data, or else it would go directly through the last point. Is that true?

I seem to remember that this is addressed in the `ggplot2` text, but I can't find it now.

Comment: I guess it would depend on the amount of error term added?? I don't quite get why it has to go thro' the last point... (On a side note, you should probably use `set.seed(.)` so that the output plot is the same when we try to plot it).

Comment: The first part of your sentence (calculated on transformed data) is right, but I don't find a relation or meaning of your second part (directly thro' last point..).

Comment: If I recall correctly, faceting comes first, and then transformations, and only then does ggplot start training scales and rendering geoms.

Comment: The linear regression is being performed on the transformed variables. Were it not, the line would not be straight on a log scale.

Comment: It's amusing to see what happens when you take out only the last scale funtion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `ggplot` renders a plot, it does so in the following order:

1. Map variables to aesthetics (ie, for each layer, figure out which variable is associated with which aesthetic, etc.)
2. Facet the datasets (make panels)
3. Transform the scales (through any `scale_` functions, typically)
4. Compute the aesthetics (ie, compute the `lm` fit, in this case -- this is where `stat_` functions come in, which are typically called through `geom_` functions)
5. Train scales (figure out what the overall plot dimensions should be)
6. Map scales (figure out where each layer should fit in the overall plot)
7. Render geoms.

So, scaling happens before the model is fit, and hence yes, the fit is being calculated on the transformed data.