# How can I add lines to connect points on regression line to both x and y axis on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add lines connecting a regression equation to specific points in the x axis and to the corresponding values on the y axis?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

x<-c(1,2,3,5,10,12,15,20,22,25,30,33,37)

y<-c(1000,800,100,10,1,0.3,0.25,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.03,0.05,0.03)

myformula<-y ~ poly(x,3)

df <- data.frame(x, y)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = myformula) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = myformula) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = myformula, eq.with.lhs = "italic(psi)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = "~italic(theta)", 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., 
                                 sep = "~~~~")), label.x=0.15, parse = TRUE)+ 
  xlim(0, 40)+  
  ylim(0, 2000)+ 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0, 0.1,10,1000), labels= c(0,0.1, 10,1000))
```

This is what I have:
[image]

And this is what I would like:
[image]

Comment: (As an aside, it seems fishy to me that the cubic fit formula and the r^2 change based on your log transformation of the y axis. i.e. without the scale transform R^2 is 0.73, with it it's 0.98 -- and the fit formula is different. I would have thought the fit would be independent of a scale transformation...)

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842505/order-of-operations-for-stat-smooth-and-scale-transformation    lm happens after the scale transform, that's why...

Answer (score 4):

You'll first want to save your plot for later use, here I'm saving it into object `p` (I'm ignoring the stuff that's not related to your question).

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = myformula) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(0, 40) +  
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0, 0.1,10,1000), labels= c(0,0.1, 10,1000))
```

The `ggplot2` package has a function `ggplot_build()` which allows you to observe all the makings of the plot.

```
plot_str <- ggplot_build(p)
```

The object created is a list, which has a `data` element, which is in itself a list of all the data frames for each of the geoms used to build the plot. Here we are interested in the line chart, which is the 2nd data frame in that list.

```
head(plot_str$data[[2]])
         x        y     ymin     ymax        se flipped_aes PANEL group  colour   fill size linetype weight alpha
1 1.000000 3.019354 2.645929 3.392780 0.1650750       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
2 1.455696 2.796358 2.458116 3.134599 0.1495218       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
3 1.911392 2.581749 2.273151 2.890348 0.1364177       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
4 2.367089 2.375366 2.090702 2.660030 0.1258375       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
5 2.822785 2.177044 1.910571 2.443518 0.1177963       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
6 3.278481 1.986621 1.732776 2.240466 0.1122137       FALSE     1    -1 #3366FF grey60    1        1      1   0.4
```

Now we can just grab a couple of points. Here I'm grabbing the 5th and the 70th row.

```
specific_points <- plot_str$data[[2]][c(5, 70), ]
```

And then getting back to the earlier version of the plot, I'm adding a few segment geoms referencing those points.

```
p + 
  geom_segment(y = specific_points$y[1], yend = specific_points$y[1], x = -Inf, xend = specific_points$x[1]) + 
  geom_segment(y = specific_points$y[1], yend = -Inf, x = specific_points$x[1], xend = specific_points$x[1], linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_segment(y = specific_points$y[2], yend = specific_points$y[2], x = -Inf, xend = specific_points$x[2]) + 
  geom_segment(y = specific_points$y[2], yend = -Inf, x = specific_points$x[2], xend = specific_points$x[2], linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that helps a lot! Do you know how can I predict the y values with known x values? Looking at the plot_str list I can get very close, but not the exact values.

Comment: I thought that is what the equation was for.

Comment: You're right. But I didn't express myself well. What I'd like to know is if there is a way to get the X values with know Y values directly through ggplot.

Answer (score 2):

(My answer doesn't quite work yet, because I haven't figured out how to replicate the scale transformation ggplot2 does before it fits the poly line. I'd love to hear any suggestions!)

My approach was to fit the curve outside of ggplot, and use those results to drive the annotations. Here's a table showing the coordinates of two points on the fitted poly line:

```
points <- c(4, 34)
lines <- data.frame(
  x = points,
  y = predict(lm(myformula), data.frame(x = points))
)
#lines
#   x       y
#1  4 370.537
#2 34  41.233
```

Then we can feed those into geom_segment:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = myformula) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_poly_eq(formula = myformula, eq.with.lhs = "italic(psi)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs = "~italic(theta)", 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., 
                                 sep = "~~~~")), label.x=0.15, parse = TRUE)+ 
  geom_segment(data = lines, lty = "dashed",
               aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = y)) +
  geom_segment(data = lines, lty = "dashed",
               aes(x = 0, xend = x, y = y, yend = y))
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work if y is transformed, as in the original question. I learned that [ggplot2 transforms the scales before it fits the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842505/order-of-operations-for-stat-smooth-and-scale-transformation), so the fit ggplot2 is using will vary from the untransformed version.

Here we see that the transformed data after adding `scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0, 0.1,10,1000), labels= c(0,0.1, 10,1000))` can be fit more closely to a cubic curve than the untransformed data, with r^2 increasing to 0.98. However, the old line segments won't work any more since the fit has changed. I will leave the correction of that fit to the reader since I can't figure it out.

[image]