# Trend line changes depending on axis scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I'm using ggplot2 and ggmics to generate a trend line.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(scales)

x <- c(5,2,6,8,9,1,3,6,8,2)
y <- c(4,7,2,5,7,9,5,2,1,3)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

g <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y))
g <- g + geom_point(colour = "black")
g <- g + stat_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x, se = FALSE)
g <- g + stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x,
                      aes(label = paste(stat(eq.label),stat(rr.label),stat(adj.rr.label),stat(p.value.label),sep = "~~~")),
                      label.x = "right",label.y = "bottom",parse = TRUE)

gg <- g + coord_trans(y = "identity")
gg <- g + coord_trans(y = "log")
gg <- g + scale_y_log10(breaks=10^(0:3),
                          labels=trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x)))
```

[image: 1]

- For `g`, the label is `y = 6.26 - 0.351x`
- For `gg`, it is `y = 0.782 - 0.0419x`

When I use exponential notation, the value of `eq.label` changes. I think the `eq.label` should not change because I am only changing the axis scale. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of operations for stat\_smooth and scale transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842505/order-of-operations-for-stat-smooth-and-scale-transformation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main thing to understand is in my opinion this information provided on the link below:

- The difference between transforming the scales and transforming the
  coordinate system is that scale transformation occurs BEFORE
  statistics, and coordinate transformation afterwards.  Coordinate
  transformation also changes the shape of geoms:

1. In case of transforamtion (scale) is BEFORE statistics, decreasing the errors of the sum of squares is performed on the transformed data.This would be ok if the relation is linear to the log of the variable.
2. This changes if you transform the coordinates because here the statistics is performed AFTER transformation. e.g. decreasing the errors of sum of squares is performed on the untransformed data.

See here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_trans.html