# ggplot crossbar mislocalization in log-scaled data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, transformation

I want to plot my data as a scatter plot with the mean+sem error bar by using `ggplot2`. I am using `stat_summary` to add the mean bar and errorbar. As the variation is pretty huge, I used `scale_y_continuous` to transform the y axis as a log10 scale for better visualization.

Here is the example data:

```
Value <- c(815,2467,4130,32588,171,68,582,476)
Treatment <- c(rep("Ctl",4),rep("Mutant",4))
data.frame(Value, Treatment)
```

It works fine when I use the linear y-axis. The crossbar localized on 10000, the mean of `Ctl` group.

```
plot_linear <- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=Value, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(color = Treatment), fill = "white", stroke = 2,
               binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 1,
               position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "crossbar", size = 1, width = 0.6, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", size = 0.5, width = 0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]
However, if I log transform the y axis, the crossbar for the mean value of `Ctl` always localizes on the second-highest point (4130) but not the mean point (10000).

```
plot_log <- dat %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=Value, color = Treatment)) +
        geom_dotplot(aes(color = Treatment), fill = "white", stroke = 2,
                     binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 1,
                     position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
        stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "crossbar", size = 1, width = 0.6, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
        stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", size = 0.5, width = 0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
        theme_bw() +
        # log scaled y axis
        scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                           breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x))
```

[image]
I don't understand the logic of this wired localization for the crossbar.

**Is there a way to plot the mean bar for the log-scaled data?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387824/r-ggplot2-using-stat-summary-mean-and-logarithmic-scale

Comment: @JonSpring, Thank you for your link. I don't think it is the one I want as `coord_trans` will changes the whole coordinate system, including the shape of the grid and breaks. And `coord_trans` cannot explain why the `scale_y_continuous` function changes the position of the mean value crossbar...

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue related to you adding the log scale after everything else, so when the error bars are made, they are made for the non-log axis and then the axis is overwritten in log scale?  I would try putting the scale_y_conintous() function first after the ggplot() function.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, even if I put the `scale_y_continuous` direct after `ggplot`, the crossbar is still located at the second-highest point...

Comment: If you transform the y data before you plot does the problem still exist? like dat$value <- log(dat$value)

Answer (score 0):

The `stat_summary` steps are performed after the transformation, which is why the mean looks different with log scale. This is described a bit here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14845174/6851825

And more technical discussion about the rationale and implications from the ggplot2 team here:

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2804

To resolve this, you have a few options.

1. Calculate your summary values upstream of ggplot2:

---

```
dat_sum <- dat %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(Value),
            mean_se = sd(Value) / sqrt(n()))

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=Value, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(color = Treatment), fill = "white", stroke = 2,
               binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 1,
               position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = dat_sum,
  aes(y = mean, ymin = mean - mean_se, ymax = mean + mean_se)) +
  geom_crossbar(data = dat_sum, 
                aes(y = mean, ymin = mean, ymax = mean)) +
theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x))
```

[image]

2. Apply the inverse transform to your summary variables. This is probably more brittle and more likely to confuse others reading the code, but it does keep the calculation within the ggplot2 chain.

---

```
dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Treatment, y=Value, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(color = Treatment), fill = "white", stroke = 2,
               binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize = 1,
               position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun = function(x) log10(mean(10^x)), geom = "crossbar", size = 1, width = 0.6, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = function(x) log10(mean_se(10^x)), geom = "errorbar", size = 0.5, width = 0.3, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(),
                     breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x))
```